# How do I get drivers working after installing Windows 10 on a MacBook Pro 2010?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I have installed windows 10 to my MacBook Pro 2010 and cannot get the drivers to work after installing the Windows Support software, Boot Camp v4.0.4033
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) Windows 7 64-bit

I used this guide,  https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp, to install Windows 10 without Boot Camp assistant with the application UNetbootin.

So it installed OK however after downloading the Boot Camp v4.0.4033 drivers for Windows 7/8 which are the drivers for the device, no sound. The sound card drivers are: Realtek high definition audio driver v6.0.1.5936

I tried installing the next version which are suitable for Windows 10, v5.1.5621, still no sound.

I did a refresh, update, and took restore points along the way, and although it is running fine, i am without sound. Bluetooth drivers also and haven't spent time on the others. The drivers are Windows 7 drivers, so it seems they are too old for Windows 10. Compatibility mode installs the drivers, but no sound. I've tried updating the drivers from device manager with the inf's and it gives the error 'A newer version of the driver is already installed.' 
At a loss here

Any thoughts on how I should proceed appreciated

Comment: There are no Win10 Boot Camp drivers for a 2010 Mac - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204990#models

Comment: but the drivers are there for the hardware. I just have to get the drivers working in windows 10

Comment: No. There are no drivers, Apple never made any. Not sure why Windows thinks the sound card is a Realtek either, it's Apple/Intel

Comment: It's realtek. They are the drivers from the Windows Support Bootcamp 4.0.4033 drivers. You go into the folder structure that apple have provided and RealTek is the audio device.